# Interactive rebase for only my commits

Tags: git, github

While working on my branch i merged the master branch to keep my work up to date with the master.

Now when I want to clean up my commit history (squash / pick) i get all the commits from the master branch as well by `git rebase myBranch -i HEAD myfirstcommit`

How can I filter out the commits from the master branch, so I can only rearrange my own commits?

Answer (score 19):

After you've merged `master` into your branch, while staying in your branch, do the following:

```
git rebase -i master
```

This will rebase your branch on top of `master`, taking only new commits, that are in your branch, but not in `master`.

Answer (score 0):

You can squash commits on your branch and than put it on the top of master :

```
git rebase -i HEAD~$(git rev-list --count origin/master..) \
    && git pull --rebase master
```

Answer (score 0):

You should clean up your commit history (pick,squash,fixup,etc) before you merge or rebase to your master branch:

```
git rebase -i HEAD~N 
# N: is number, how many last N commit you want to "clean"
```

After that you can merge or rebase to your master branch.